# Java JSON Controller to Scala?

Tags: java, json, scala, playframework-2.0

I am having a harder time than I would like to admit understanding the [JSON documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson).

I would like to convert this JSON result to Scala, but I'm pretty lost. I have tried a lot of things, but I'm still learning Scala as well, so none of it is really worth posting as I'm not even sure if it makes sense.

I am using the Anorm ORM in Scala. The id is a `Pk[Long]`

```
public static Result checkName(String clubname){
      ObjectNode jresult = Json.newObject();

     if (Club.clubExists(clubname)) {
         jresult.put("error", "Club Name Exists");
         return status(409, jresult); // 409 - Conflict
     } else {
         jresult.put("status", "OK");
         return ok(jresult);
     }
 }
```

clubExists in the model:

```
public static boolean clubExists(String name) {
    Club club = find.where().eq("club_name", name).findUnique();
    return (club != null);
}
```

The rest of the model is pretty basic:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "club_seq")
public Long clubId;

@Column(unique=true, length = 50)
public String clubName;

public Long creator;
public DateTime created;

public Club(String clubName, Long creator) {
    this.clubName = clubName;
    this.creator = creator;
    this.created = new DateTime();
}

public static Finder<Long, Club> find = new Finder<Long, Club>(Long.class, Club.class);

public static Club create(String name, Long creator) {
    Club club = new Club(name, creator);
    club.save();
    return club;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static Result checkName(String clubname){
     ObjectNode jresult = Json.newObject();

     if (Club.clubExists(clubname)) {
         jresult.put("error", "Club Name Exists");
         return status(409, jresult); // 409 - Conflict
     } else {
         jresult.put("status", "OK");
         return ok(jresult);
     }
}
```

in Scala is (adding `as JSON` to change the MIME type):

```
def checkName(clubName:String) = Action {
  val jresult = Json.obj()
  if (Club.exists(clubName)) {
    Conflict(jresult) as JSON
  } else {
    Ok(jresult) as JSON
  } 
}
```